# How to validate against a Model's metadata through a custom ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm working on a webapp using ASP MVC. I'm building a page to edit a user's data (model USER, view ModifyUser).

I have a model with validations in this manner:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(USERS_Metadata))]
public partial class USER
{
    public class USERS_Metadata
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "FALTA NOMBRE")]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Nombre entre 3 y 30 caracteres", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage = "Error en el formato del nombre.")]
        public string NAME { get; set; }
```

I then use a view that automagically validates user inputs:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SURNAME) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.SURNAME) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SURNAME) %>
    </div>
```

The problem is my view is also gonna need to access some other entities with their own models, like USERCATEGORY, which makes using an strongly typed view a bit more uncomfortable.

Aditionally, and may be even more important, I don't want my view to have to deal with, and even knowing about, properties such as the user's session ID, which currently I handle like this (and i hate it):

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SESSIONID) %>
```

Unless I'm utterly mistaken, the most sane option is to build a custom ViewModel. I decided to build my ModifyUserViewModel to match those fields in USER I'm gonna need in my view, and add a few fields from the other models... But I have no idea of how to propagate the metadata in USER, that I use for field validation, to the new ViewModel. This metadata is automatically built from the database, and copypasting it would make me feel dead inside, even if it works.

What is the canonical, most maintenable, easiest way to validate from the View like I am currently doing, but with a ViewModel?

Comment: Why do you need to attach that hidden for sessionId? Are you using it anywhere?

Comment: If I don't, after submission it complains that sessionId can not be null (it tries to validate the whole model).

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your view model as an aggregate of several domain models:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public USER User { get; set; }
    public USERCATETORY Category { get; set; }
}
```

See a great article [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx).